# What books can help me to avoid writing mistakes?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

I need some book or books that teach me how to avoid that my German teacher marks what I write as an "error", when I have used three websites to correct my writing and the three have declared that "Es wurden keine Fehler gefunden."

The websites that I used are:

- https://www.languagetool.org/de/
- https://rechtschreibpruefung24.de/
- https://mentor.duden.de/

In the following examples, the first sentence is what I wrote and the second sentence is how my teacher says that it should have been written. I need a way to write, as he wants me to write, or else ...

Examples:

- Man muss sprechen, hören, lesen und schreiben zu Deutsch lernen.
- Man muss sprechen, hören, lesen und schreiben, um Deutsch zu lernen.

---

- Bei der Abteilung für Germanistik arbeiten sehr gute Leute, die haben eine Liste vorbereitet.
- Bei der Abteilung für Germanistik arbeiten sehr gute Leute, die eine Liste vorbereitet haben.

---

- Die Menschen kann benutzen die Liste, wenn sie weißen nicht was zu schreiben.
- Man kann die Liste benutzen, wenn man nicht weiß, was zu schreiben.

---

- Schreiben Sie auf, was heute ist passiert.
- Schreiben Sie darüber, was heute passiert ist.

---

- Schreiben Sie auf Ihr Job.
- Schreiben Sie über Ihren Job.

---

- Schreiben Sie auf, Ihre Schule.
- Schreiben Sie über Ihre Schule.

---

- Schreiben Sie auf Ihr am besten Freund.
- Schreiben Sie über Ihren besten Freund.

---

- Schreiben Sie auf eine lustig Erlebnis.
- Schreiben Sie über ein lustiges Erlebnis.

Comment: Google can help you. Google for the sentence, if it had only minor mistakes (for example, bad prepositions), you will likely find the correct sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those grammar checks a software can do are very simplistic, because a software doesn't know about the meaning of a sentence.

You need a book on German grammar. Your teacher should have recommended you one, preferably written in your native language.

Problems I see in your attempts:

> <s>Man muss sprechen, hören, lesen und schreiben zu Deutsch lernen.</s>
>
> Man muss sprechen, hören, lesen und schreiben, um Deutsch zu lernen.

You have to learn about the *Infinitivsatz* (*infinitive clause*) and especially its very common *um … zu* variant.

> Bei der Abteilung für Germanistik arbeiten sehr gute Leute, die haben eine Liste vorbereitet.

This isn't even wrong but not what your teacher expected. You have concatenated two main clauses instead of using a subordinate/relative clause. These clauses have a different word order, that's how one can spot it.

> <s>Die Menschen kann benutzen die Liste, wenn sie weißen nicht was zu schreiben.</s>
>
> Man kann die Liste benutzen, wenn man nicht weiß, was zu schreiben **ist**.

Your teacher missed the *ist*, as you did. The phrase *…, was zu [Infinitiv] ist* is special, it means *…, what has to be [Infinitiv]*. The verb *weißen* exists! But it means *to whiten*, not *to know*. Get your verbs right. Also, be more careful about singular and plural forms. Learn about the placement of *nicht*. It only goes at the end of a clause if it's a main clause and you want to negate the predicate verb.

> <s>Schreiben Sie auf, was heute ist passiert.</s>
>
> Schreiben Sie darüber, was heute passiert ist.

A clause lead by a question word which isn't a question is a subordinate clause and needs to follow the word order of subordinate clauses. Second, if it was a question (and thus, a main clause), the predicate verb had to be in second position. The *auf/darüber* correction is unnecessary. Both are good fits here.

> <s>Schreiben Sie auf Ihr Job.</s>
>
> Schreiben Sie über Ihren Job.

This is a matter of learning the correct prepositions for a verb. *Schreiben über + Akkusativ* means *to write about*, while *schreiben auf + Akkusativ* means *to write on (paper etc.)*. You also made the mistake of using the nominative *Ihr Job* instead of the accusative.

The other examples you gave are just the same.

Comment: Dear Sir or Madam: I have searched all over this site and the META site looking for a means to contact you, and found only why an user should not contact another user, and that I ought to use the email that appears in your profile. But, as your profile contains no email address (or any other thing), I am compelled to write a comment to say to you: Thanks, thanks for spending your time in answering my question. And if I have to be punished for using a comment to say “Thanks”, let it be so, but I have been taught by my parents that one should always be grateful to those that help you.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Err ... you should not even try to rely on any software whatsoever. It's **you** who has to learn things. If you don't, they won't be at your disposition. Mistakes like * *"Die Menschen kann"* -> plural + singular form or * *"eine lustig Erlebnis"* -> , feminine indefinite article, uninflected adjective + neuter noun show that you have missed the essentials. Take seriously what's in your course book, learn it, and forget about any additional books.